# Finding transfer function with Fast Fourier Fransform.

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have two signals with input = a(t) and output = b(t) that have been sampled every 0.01s and as such the fast Fourier transform has been used on both and utilised to produce a transfer function.

The only problem is that currently I'm left with a massive list of complex values. How would one find a closed form type expression for such a system? I imagine I need to find the poles and zeros?

Edit: For clarity I would like to say that I used numpy.FFT (python language) and it produces an array of complex values. This was applied to both a(t) and b(t). The FFT of b was divided by the FFT of a. This leaves me with an array of complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let A(f) and B(f) be the FFT's from a(t) respectively b(t).

Then you're supposed to take the inverse FFT from B(f)/A(f).
It will result in an array of real values that identifies the transfer function with respect to time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @i-like-selenaa ... I've often seen transfer functions expressed as polynomials with s's in the numerator and denominator for the case of laplace transforms. Won't your suggestion provide me with an impulse response?

Comment: I just ran the inverse on B/A and still have complex values. EDIT: Just noticed that they are of tiny order though like e^-14.

Comment: Close enough. The transfer function convolves with the input function to yield the output function. If your input function would be the impulse function, the output function happens to be the same as the transfer function, which is why the impulse response is so important. Note that Laplace transforms are  identical to Fourier transforms with $s=i\omega$.

Comment: Yep. Those tiny order imaginary values would be rounding errors as you may have surmised.

Comment: I just took a plot to see what it would look like (with just the real values) and it's a spikey mess! Do I want to try and fit a function to this?

Comment: Also it is symmetrical either side of t/2. Currently reading up on transfer functions like crazy to make sense of this!

Comment: If it's a spikey mess then there may not be a recognizable transfer function. What is the origin of your samples?

Comment: Input = z axis accelerometer reading * mass of accelerometer. Output = force output from a force plate and thus also z axis. (wiimote and wiiboard!). Plotting the two together against time gives me almost identical shaped graphs with a difference in amplitude that is a constant multiple of the accelerometer. It was hypothesised that this was due to contributions from the swinging of the arm and a "missing mass" was calculated with f_board/a_z - m_remote. Achieved this by comparing integrals of both signals and it yielded a constant. Changing input to a_remote*(m_remote+m_missing) fixed this.

Comment: If your output function has the same shape as your input function (except for a factor), the transfer function would be the impulse function: a large spike at zero. Due to the properties of the FFT that spike would be mirrored at the maximum time value. The remainder of the transfer function would be noise .

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting from numerical data and want to estimate an analytical expression for it, then you will have to perform some sort of model fit to the data. For signal modeling, you can search for topics such as least squares, Pade approximations, and Prony's method to name a few.

[Here](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF4480/v10/undervisningsmateriale/spII_SignalModellering_handout.pdf) are some slides I quickly found with google that wil provide a starting point for you.