# Compute Transfer Function from FFT of Input and Output

Tags: signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

I tried the method described in a previous answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718856/451691) to compute the transfer function of a system I am studying, where:

> In(t) = a(t); Out(t) = b(t)

I did as suggested below using a Scilab code:

> Let A(f) and B(f) be the FFT's from a(t) respectively b(t).
>
> Then you're supposed to take the inverse FFT from B(f)/A(f). It will result > in an array of real values that identifies the transfer function with respect to time.

But, when I multiply this array (that I call `h`) by the array of input values, the result is massively different from the output values I computed resolving the system's differential equations.
In symbols:

> h = IFFT(B(f)/A(f))
>
> In(t)*h ~= Out(t)

What is wrong with this method?

Comment: The discrete Fourier transform (DFT) only applies to vectors $\in \mathbb{C}^N$, not functions of $t \in \mathbb{R}$. The main property of the DFT is that  $y(n) = x \ast h(n) \iff Y(k) = X(k) H(k)$ where $ \ast $ is the circular convolution and $X(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n) e^{-2i \pi nk/N}, x(n) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X(k) e^{2 i \pi nk/N}$. With zero-padding, the circular convolution becomes just a convolution.

Comment: Alright for the basic maths. How does this help me solve the problem at hand?

Comment: It helps you because you are multiplying when you should be convolving.